# Keeping PHPDoc comments in blade templates up to date with Laravel Controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, phpdoc

My project has a number of Controllers with `$data` arrays that are then passed to `\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::view::getResponse`. Other developers on my team will often add new keys to the `$data` array without updating the PHPDoc comments in the Blade template, making it look like their templates are using undefined variables.

Is there a way to keep these in sync without relying on human memory? (I'm hoping for some kind of "inherit vars from *this* interface," etc.)

Comment: You can use IDE Plugins.

Comment: Like: `public function method(PeopleShouldFollowThisKey $data)`

Comment: Your IDE should be complaining about any use of an undeclared variable in the template.